# Android RadioButton icon disappears when singleline set to true and text gravity set to right

Tags: android, radio-button, gravity

I found a weird situation on Android RadioButton, when I set singleline to true and setGravity to right, the radio icon disappears. Anyone know what causes this problem and how to make it shows the icon normally while setting singleline to true and gravity to right? The xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:text="hello" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        android:text="hello2" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

And here is what it looks like:
[image]

Notice the first radiobutton, the icon is gone.

Comment: Provide your code here

Comment: Show us the XML for your RadioButton.